# Angular Material fabSpeedDial

Tags: angularjs, floating-action-button, angularjs-material

Angular Material fabSpeedDial is not working in Andriod Mobile.

(**Important Note:ISSUE OCCURS IN ANDRIOD MOBILE ONLY WHEN I USE, jquery-2.2.3.min.js**)

I have a demo code taken from the following codepen link

[Angular Material fabSpeedDial](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/fabSpeedDial)

If i remove that jquery-2.2.3.min.js, then the functionality works fine both in mobile and desktop.

But iam in a situation where i cannot remove this jquery-2.2.3.min.js. I also tried having lower version of jquery like 2.2.2 , 2.2.1 etc, but same results.

Please help me in finding a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed after updating angular-material.js to v0.11.2